# Remembering state with react

Tags: reactjs

I am making a comment feature with React that has nested comments. The user can choose to view replies to a comment by clicking "view replies." Subcomments Viewed/Hidden are part of the comment box state. The user can also post an entirely new comment.

My problem is that when you post a new comment it collapses all of the comments which were currently expanded. Posting a new comment causes the program to go fetch all of the main comments and this is re rendering the comments.

How can i can make react "remember" the old comments with their state intact?

On a side note: I have a similar implementation for just liking comments and liking does not cause React to create completely new comments, even though I am also going back to fetch all the comments after a user likes a comment. Another thing that might help answer my main question is how does react decide to completely recreate a component or just use the updated props to update a component?

Comment: react has a virtual DOM that determines what is different and replaces what it needs to you should look at how they do it.. do you have a store or anything you are using for the state? (flux pattern)

Comment: Yes, I am using flux. I update the main comment store when a new comment is posted.

Comment: does your main comment store have an array of comments and you render a child component for every one?

Comment: Are you submitting the form causing a page refresh? Did you remember to add `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: I did prevent default. I think I fixed it actually. Typing out the question helped me think about it more.

Comment: daniel if you fixed it yourself then you can delete the question or post your answer so it can be closed

Answer (score 0):

React always looks for changes between old and new props and state, and only renders differences.

If you want the *content* of the subcomments remembered, better to store them somewhere and pass them as props. State is (almost by definition) not for remembering.

I think that state is not lost when you re-render a mounted component. So you could pass a prop to that says view/hidden, and use css styling/ classnames to show/ hide the element.

If your top component does not even render the subcomments when they are hidden, then they will be uncounted and state is lost.

Hop this makes sense

Comment: To add to this, in addition to props and state changes, context changes can also trigger an update.